# CSS, why won't my ID take priority over my class?

Tags: html, css

so what I learned is that in CSS, the id selector takes priority over the class selector, yet for some reason, adding an id to my desired paragraph, and changing its position won't have any effect on it, would love some advise.

```css
.stats {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: guy;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#queue {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <p>Online Users: 100</p>
  <p id="queue">Players in Queue: 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In any case, *priority* only concerns the *same* selected element, otherwise it's more of a *cascade*. `text-align: left` for the containing block can perfectly well co-exist with `text-align: right` on a contained block. That said, yes, the computed value for `text-align` for any contained block would be inherited from containing block, unless a `text-align` rule exists for the contained element. But cascading and priority are two different things here, really. And not all values are inherited in a child from parent, yet, with multiple selectors for a child, priority still matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute` is the culprit as it will make the width shrink-to-fit thus there is nothing to align since the content will define the width

Add border to better see the issue:

```css
.stats {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: guy;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  border:1px solid;
}

#queue {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <p>Online Users: 100</p>
  <p id="queue">Players in Queue: 1</p>
</div>
```

What you need is to make the element `width:100%` by using `left:0; right:0;`

```css
.stats {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: guy;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  border:1px solid;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

#queue {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <p>Online Users: 100</p>
  <p id="queue">Players in Queue: 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use position:relative in the stats class to achieve the same effect

Comment: @shmit relative is not the same as absolute so we won't have the same effect

Comment: I seem to have a problem. Why is this happening once the stats start (line in the middle) its like seperating the page https://gyazo.com/280c93c41aafdf78d527f9b392772a12

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the `position: absolute;` of the parent, which causes the width to shrink to the content's (i.e. text) width (therefore `text-align` has no effect). If you remove that, you see the expected result. (You might want to use `margin-top` instead of the absolute position to get some distance from the top)

```css
.stats {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: guy;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#queue {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <p>Online Users: 100</p>
  <p id="queue">Players in Queue: 1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your position absolute takes the div element out of the normal document flow. If you give the .stat class a width, it should respond as you intended:

```css
.stats {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: guy;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#queue {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <p>Online Users: 100</p>
  <p id="queue">Players in Queue: 1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've learned is good, but the reason why you don't see the results is that you need to provide a min-width to your div.

Add this to the div.state:
**`.stats {min-width: 100%;}`**

Hope it helps.